# C# how Set property dynamically by string?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, properties, set

First of all I'm not into programming, but could figure out the basic concept
up to my needs.

In the below code, I want to set the property by name "Gold" in something like:

```
_cotreport.Contract = COTReportHelper.ContractType."Blabalbal"


 protected override void OnBarUpdate()
            {

                COTReport _cotreport = COTReport(Input);
                _cotreport.Contract=COTReportHelper.ContractType.Gold;
                _cotreport.OpenInterestDisplay=COTReportHelper.OpenInterestDisplayType.NetPosition;
                double index = _cotreport.Commercial[0];
                OwnSMA.Set(index);

            }
```

I tried below code, but the system says: "

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*

Please help!

```
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo PropertyInfo = _cotreport.GetType().GetProperty("ContractType");
            PropertyInfo.SetValue(_cotreport.Contract,"Gold",null);
            PropertyInfo.SetValue(_cotreport.Contract,Convert.ChangeType("Gold",PropertyInfo.PropertyType),null);
```

Comment: hit google before asking questions

Comment: "In blow code"? Nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set get a property named `"ContractType"` on `_cotreport` and set it's value with on `_cotreport.Contract`. That's not going to work for two reasons.

1. The property name (from what I can tell in your code) is `Contract` not `ContractType`.
2. You need to set the value on `_cotreport`.

Try this instead

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = _cotreport.GetType().GetProperty("Contract");
property.SetValue(_cotreport, COTReportHelper.ContractType.Gold, new object[0]);
```

If you want to set the enum value by name, that's a separate issue. Try this

```
var enumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(COTReportHelper.ContractType), "Gold");
property.SetValue(_cotreport, enumValue, new object[0]);
```

Comment: var enumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(COTReportHelper.ContractType), "Gold");
property.SetValue(_cotreport, enumValue, new object[0]); is the solution, thanks a lot !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyInfo`could be `null`, and may not be if you used the property name: `Contract`. And you should be able to specify `COTReportHelper.ContractType.Gold` as the value directly. And you specify the *property* as the instance to be modified, but the `PropertyInfo` represents that, you should specify the owning instance on which the property value should be set.

Something like this:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo PropertyInfo = _cotreport.GetType().GetProperty("Contract");
PropertyInfo.SetValue(_cotreport, COTReportHelper.ContractType.Gold, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method sets value of property of any object and returns true if assignment was successfull:

```
public static Boolean TrySettingPropertyValue(Object target, String property, String value)
{
        if (target == null)
            return false;
        try
        {
            var prop = target.GetType().GetProperty(property, DefaultBindingFlags);
            if (prop == null)
                return false;
            if (value == null)
                prop.SetValue(target,null,null);
            var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType);
            prop.SetValue(target,convertedValue,null);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you,error: the name" DefaultBindingFlags" does not exist in the current context.